# dynamic routes don't work with array.map()

Tags: reactjs

I am struggling to fix the issue where I want to make the dynamic routes.
I have a routes.js looks like below:

```
import UpdatePassword from "../../components/Admin/UpdatePassword";
import UpdateDetails from "../../components/Admin/UpdateDetails";
import Dashboard from "../../components/Admin/Dashboard";

const routes = [
    {path: '/admin', exact:true, name:'Admin' },
    {path: '/admin/dashboard', exact: true, name:'Dashboard', element:Dashboard},
    {path: '/admin/update-password', exact: true, name:'UpdatePassword', element: UpdatePassword},
    {path: '/admin/update-details', exact: true, name: 'UpdateDetails', element: UpdateDetails},
];

export default routes;
```

And this is my MasterLayout.js file where I am getting all routes here:

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import routes from "../../components/routes/routes";
import {Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';


const MasterLayout = () => (

    <div className="container-scroller">
        <Navbar/>

        <div className="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
            <Sidebar/>

        <div className="main-panel">

            <div className="content-wrapper">
                    <Routes>
                    {
                        routes.map((route,idx)=> {

                            return(
                                route.element && (
                                         <Route
                                            key= {idx}
                                            name= {route.name}
                                            path = {route.path}
                                            exact = {route.exact}
                                            render={(props) => ( <route.element{...props} />
                                        )}/>
                            )
                        )})
                    }
                    <Navigate to="/admin/dashboard"/>
                    </Routes>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
);

export default MasterLayout;
```

And finally my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Routes, Route } from 'react-router';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import MasterLayout from "./layouts/Admin/MasterLayout";


const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                {/*We get only single file that contains everything*/}
                <Route path="/admin/" name="Admin" render={(props) => <MasterLayout {...props}/> } ></Route>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

I can't find the mistake as when I try to load the `www.mywebsite.com/admin/dashboard` it says : `No routes matched location "/admin/dashboard"`.
This is how my files and folders are ordered:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing Routes from one file.

Comment: Tried and got an error : `Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.`

Answer (score 0):

Try with nested routes this way.

```
<Route path="/admin" element={<User />}>
   <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Comp />} />
   <Route path="/update-password" element={<Comp />} />
</Route>
```

Just remove /admin from routes.js file for nested routes

Comment: But this is not what I was asking in my question. I need dynamic links which has the same sidebar, navbar and etc. I have to bring MasterLayout to `api.js` file and show whatever link it is. Do you mean to add this nested routes in the MasterLayout file?

Comment: my MasterLayout.js file contains Sidebar, Navbar , Footer and Content part. So aim here is to find the way to call MasterLayout inside of the Api.js

Comment: 2 ways to do that, 
1: move header footer to App.js if whole site have same layout.
2: Create a separate component <AdminLayout/> with header and footer and pass it to path="/admin". and nested route say path="/dashboard" with its own component, that you have in routes.js file

Comment: I actually don't want to move the header and footer to there as the layout will not be the same for full website. This is only admin panel layout. Why I am not able to use .map() here that is what I am trying to find out. Because this is the most optimal way I want to make it happen.

Comment: because as I mentioned, one issue is your path for nested routes are finally like "/admin/admin/dashboard" which should be "/admin/dashboard"

Comment: as you did'nt  set the parent "/admin" path and element

Comment: one thing is, you are trying to do nested routes, but your routes array is not good for that.

Comment: I have done this based on the tutorial and in that video it works fine, interestingly it doesn't in my case. and how it should be looking like you think ?

Comment: try to follow this, https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/

Comment: the link you provided does not have sufficient information as it only provides the map() function usage with only different id numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I was not able to get the matched route is the element value inside of the array below:

```
const routes = [
    {path: '/admin', exact:true, name:'Admin' },
    {path: '/admin/dashboard', exact: true, name:'Dashboard', element:Dashboard},
    {path: '/admin/update-password', exact: true, name:'UpdatePassword', element: UpdatePassword},
    {path: '/admin/update-details', exact: true, name: 'UpdateDetails', element: UpdateDetails},
];
```

As you see element names are not correct, as they should be like `<UpdateDetails />` instead. There are plenty people who is not able to find the solution, so I hope this will help.